# Typo3 9.5 - Custom flexform ordering, wrong backquotes in sql

Tags: repository, typo3, sql-order-by, typo3-9.x, flexform

i have an custom extension, where you can select the different entries at the backend, to show them at the list view. I have a custom sorting at my backend, but the system always sort them Descending.

I implemented an "orderBy" function, which doesnt work, because the system uses wrong backspaces.

My code looks like this:

I call the sort function in my "findByUid($uid)" function like this:

```
$query->setOrderings($this->orderByKey('uid', $uidArray));


protected function orderByKey($key, $uidlist) {
    $order = array();
    foreach ($uidlist as $uid) {
        //$order["$key=$uid"] = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING;
        $order["$key=$uid"] = "ASC";
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($order);
    }
    return $order;
}
```

The result at the sql query is:

```
ORDER BY `tx_MYEXTENSION_domain_model_FIELD`.`uid=3` DESC
```

But it must be:

```
ORDER BY `tx_MYEXTENSION_domain_model_FIELD`.`uid` = 3 DESC
```

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, I found this solution on an stackoverflow entry:

```
$ids = explode(',',$this->settings['entries'])
foreach($ids as $key => $id){
  $entries[$id] = $this->entriesRepository->findByUid($id);
}
```

This code snippet has to be intergrated at the controller.
For me its working.